# How can I send mail to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, sql-server-2005

Is there any option to send mail to SQL Server 2005 and in response get some report or result of some function or start a procedure?

Thanks for answers

Comment: I strongly suggest to avoid this option. I think that you can follow different ways in order to achieve the goal you're asking for. What about any middle layer which manages the "email requests" and, based on a business logic, which ask for a SQL Server report (or report generation process)? However, you can find more details here (similar question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975414/receiving-email-with-sql-server-sql-2008r2

Comment: No, SQL Server itself doesn't have any POP infrastructure - SQL Server cannot "receive" e-mails. You'll need to think of another way to get this done

Comment: Why do you want to send an email to sql server ? Why can't you have a log table for this instead ?

Comment: I want to make possible that some user that don't have permission to server send email and receive a report. So I will not have to do that. I wan't to make it automatic. Got some solution?